# Centering content without divs

Tags: html, css

I recently ran across this ["article"](http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres) that explains how to center content with only the use of the html and body tag.  But what I can't not figure out is how to make a full width header and footer while still having my content centered using this method.  Any suggestions?

Comment: why do you want it without div? what about your header and footer you mentioned, aren't they in div?

Comment: I was just looking for a shortcut to centering content.  Just testing it out.  But it seems this method hinders flexibility of my header and footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, if you use the `body` tag as a `div`, then any other `div`s inside it will only have the width of the `body` tag. So

```
body {
    width: 200px; 
    margin: 20px auto; 
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

will make any `div`s have a maximum width of 200px.

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4wkf4/) jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I encountered.

Comment: @BrandonDorsey So making any `div` inside the `body` have a 'full width' will only give it the width of the `body` tag. You should use `div`s inside the `body` tag to center/layout content.

Comment: That is what i normally do, but I thought that there was a way to achieve the same effect using camen's method.  I guess it is back to wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

this article explains, that you can center content with 
`margin: 20px auto;`
you need to give the footer and the header the same css.
at least, it would be easier, more readable and structured, if you use div-blocks. that is, what div-blocks are for...structure your website.

Comment: Well apparently, the guy who uses this method thinks that it is better to use this method than div blocks.  I was just seeing if you could add a full width header and footer.

Comment: no, IMHO he just emphasis that body itself is a container. ask yourself what html element (beside of div you want to avoid) do you want to use when you have header, content, and footer and you only focus on 1 container (that is body)

Comment: He clearly states towards the bottom: "And remember, that’s a body element you’re looking at, no wrapper! So no more excuses. Stop using wrappers".

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I mis-read the question and rewrote my answer as this:

There are two ways to accomplish what you want. First is to absolutely position the element which will take it out of the flow and allow you to expand the width outside of the body but this can complicate some elements. The second is to use negative margins. I'm being pulled away but I'll try and give an example later if no one else does.

EDIT: Slapped this together real quick.

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
        body{width:980px;margin:0}
        p{position:absolute;width:100%;background:#ccc;}
</style>
<p>One</p>
```

Comment: It sure looks like he is using the body as a wrapper for the content. Therefore, whatever content that lies inside of that body will only extend as far as the set width.  However, my concern lies with the header and footer not being able to stretch 100%, which is relatively easy using divs.

Comment: @BrandonDorsey - That's what I'm saying so perhaps I'm mis-reading your question. I thought you were thinking the content of the body would be centered auto-magically by applying this.

Comment: @BrandonDorsey - I've got to quit reading this stuff first thing in the morning and I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: tried to make header / footer stretch, and it was a complete fail.

Comment: @BrandonDorsey - Sorry. Make the p position:absolute;

Comment: @Rob- Tried that.  The header stretches but it seems to float to the right, and has about 50px+ of marginal spacing on the left.  This seems to be more trouble than it is actually worth.

Comment: @BrandonDorsey - It shouldn't have any margin at all. Are you using exactly what I show?

Comment: Yeah man, I previewing in the latest version of safari / chrome.  I'm using a reset as well.  The only thing different in my code is that I have margin 0 auto for centering the body.

Comment: I'm driving myself crazy doing this and something else. I forgot about the body as you show. You need to apply a negative margin to p to center it. I'm going to stop replying because I can't focus on this right now. Sorry.

Comment: Hey Rob, I ran into this ["article"](http://csswizardry.com/2011/01/using-the-body-element-as-a-wrapper/)

Comment: No worries.  I found an alternative solution by using a pseudo-element.

Comment: @BrandonDorsey - Well, yes, we use the body as a wrapper all the time.

Comment: I was unaware as I am new to css.